# How to change font on XSSFTextBox

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

## XSSFTextBox and XSSFRichTextField's

**Edit see comment; Apache POI seems to be racist, black not supported? Red is?**

**Edit 2 : instead of using XSSFColor use constants in Font, they have Red and Black; looking into default Fonts (Just to be clear code now correctly displays color and size now, but the Font name/ actual font still is wrong. So Font.COLOR_NORMAL works for dat black)**

For some reason I can't get my XSSFTextBoxs' texts' fonts and font colors to change from their (I assume) default Calibri white (why is white a default?!?). I get their sizes changed, but their font and font color stay the defaults. I have found that this was a previous bug that should be fixed [**here**](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52219).

I've been looking at [*this*](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DrawingShapes) reference to base how I change the font, and it seems like this is how it's done, but it just doesn't seem to be working; I'd love another set of eyes on this, there are other minor problems I'm still fiddling with, but the font implementation is the biggest thing right now; any criticisms are welcome and wanted!

What really irks me is that I've used XSSFFont with XSSFCellStlyes before, quite extensively, and have never had any problems changing fonts or colors, let alone anything else, so I don't know if it's some strange behavior that I'm not seeing or if I've done something incorrectly here.

### Code

```
package excelhandling;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

/**Unit Tests<br>To test random things to figure them out so I can implement them
 * in the real code later; ideal is to test kinks here so whole application
 * doesn't have to be loaded over and over to figure small issues out (living the dream)
 * 
 * @author Sean Newell
 */
public class UnitTests
{

    static String fileName = "TestWorkbook.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sht = wb.createSheet();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        int colStart = 5;

        XSSFDrawing draw = sht.createDrawingPatriarch();

        XSSFShapeGroup group = draw.createGroup(draw.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, colStart, 11, colStart + 6, 11+7));
        group.setCoordinates(colStart, 11, colStart + 6, 11+7);

        XSSFTextBox tb1 = group.createTextbox(new XSSFChildAnchor(0, 0, 6, 7));
        tb1.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.RECT);
        tb1.setNoFill(false);
        tb1.setFillColor(255, 255, 255); //This causes excel to repair xml - don't know why;
        //following message from Excel:
        //Repaired Records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part (Drawing shape)
        //Log:

//      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
//      -<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
//          <logFileName>error094800_07.xml</logFileName>
//          <summary>Errors were detected in file 'H:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\TemplateBuilder\TestWorkbook.xlsx'</summary>
//              -<repairedRecords summary="Following is a list of repairs:">
//      <repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part (Drawing shape)</repairedRecord>
//          </repairedRecords>
//      </recoveryLog>

        XSSFRichTextString address = new XSSFRichTextString("TextBox string 1\nHas three\nLines to it");

        XSSFFont arial10 = wb.createFont();
        arial10.setFontName("Arial"); // Doesn't seem to work
        arial10.setFontHeight(10);
        arial10.setColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK)); // Doesn't seem to work
        address.applyFont(arial10); // Possible problem?

        tb1.setText(address);
        tb1.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);
        tb1.setLineWidth(2);


        XSSFTextBox tb2 = group.createTextbox(new XSSFChildAnchor(0, 7, 10, 13));
        tb2.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.RECT);
        tb2.setNoFill(false);
        tb2.setFillColor(254, 254, 254); //This causes excel to repair xml - don't know why
        XSSFRichTextString secret = new XSSFRichTextString("A single-line thing that has like, a lot of text, but can wrap and be smaller, like, totally.");

        XSSFFont arial8 = wb.createFont();
        arial8.setFontName("Arial"); // Doesn't seem to work
        arial8.setFontHeight(8);
        arial8.setColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK)); // Doesn't seem to work
        secret.applyFont(arial8); // Possible problem?

        tb2.setText(secret);
        tb2.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);
        tb2.setLineWidth(2);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fout;
            fout = new FileOutputStream(file);

            wb.write(fout);
            fout.close();

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Excel sheet written");
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

        } catch (IOException exc) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please close other instances of excel that have " + fileName + " open");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the color to red and the text changed to red :| It seems Black is not supported. New racism? Maybe. Going to try and check and see what fonts are supported and what colors are supported.

Comment: Been a while since I used poi.  With the old .xls format at least, the colors were constrained to the document's palette.  Using one of the constants, such as BLACK, didn't always refer to the color black, but rather the slot in the palette which was black in the default palette.  If you had changed the palette, BLACK referred to whatever color was in that slot.

Comment: Makes sense I guess; what you see is all I'm working with in this test class - so I didn't explicitly change it; do you think that the palette is like the Styles Table you get from getStylesSource()?
[**Link**](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.7-beta2/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/StylesTable.java#StylesTable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite crude, but in poi 3.9 it seems that only the font family but not the font name is copied from the `XSSFFont` object in `XSSFSimpleShape.applyAttributes`.
Furthermore I could only set indexed colors via `XSSFColor.setColor(HSSFColor.<color>.index)` - maybe there is XSSF-pendant to the [HSSF custom color palette](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CustomColors), but I think the below approach is more straight-forward ...

(Tested with Libre Office 4.0, MS Excel Viewer, MS Excel 2003 with compatibility pack ...)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTTextCharacterProperties;

public class XlsColors {

    static String fileName = "TestWorkbook.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sht = wb.createSheet();
        File file = new File(fileName);
        int colStart = 5;

        XSSFDrawing draw = sht.createDrawingPatriarch();

        XSSFShapeGroup group = draw.createGroup(draw.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, colStart, 11, colStart + 6, 11+7));
        group.setCoordinates(colStart, 11, colStart + 6, 11+7);

        XSSFTextBox tb1 = group.createTextbox(new XSSFChildAnchor(0, 0, 6, 7));
        tb1.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 0);
        tb1.setLineWidth(2);
        Color col = Color.orange;
        tb1.setFillColor(col.getRed(), col.getGreen(), col.getBlue());

        XSSFRichTextString address = new XSSFRichTextString("TextBox string 1\nHas three\nLines to it");
        tb1.setText(address);        
        CTTextCharacterProperties rpr = tb1.getCTShape().getTxBody().getPArray(0).getRArray(0).getRPr();
        rpr.addNewLatin().setTypeface("Trebuchet MS");
        rpr.setSz(900); // 9 pt
        col = Color.pink;
        rpr.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{(byte)col.getRed(),(byte)col.getGreen(),(byte)col.getBlue()});

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(fout);
        fout.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you get the same messages in libre office/Excel viewer, but in Microsoft Excel 2010 on the rpr.addNewSolidFill()... call when the file is opened in excel Excel does an xml repairing thing again; and it doesn't seem to add the fill in the background of the textbox either. Tested Color.Pink and Color.White and neither worked, so I went back to using the setFillColor on the XSSFTextBox object; still makes excel repair xml though.

Comment: The color was for the text itself, not the background. Hope I'll have time to check it with Excel 2003 at work tomorrow ...

Comment: The test under MS Excel 2003 with compatibility pack was ok, i.e. no warnings. Furthermore I've added a background color ... not nice to the eyes, but it works ;)